# Como funciona una consulta a una base de datos SQL cuando hay varios datos con el mismo nombre

Tags: java, mysql

Me encuentro con una base de datos local MySQL que contiene una tabla clientes y otra equipos

En la tabla **clientes** registro los clientes del sistema y en la de **equipos** registros los equipos pertenecientes a un cliente en común

La tabla equipo tiene una columna que es **id_cliente** en la cual se registra el id que tiene registrado el cliente en la tabla clientes al que pertenece el equipo

Necesito **consultar** los equipos registrados a nombre de un mismo cliente y solo de ese cliente

Pará esto:

Debo escribir **una sola instrucción para todos** lo equipos de un mismo cliente(Si es así, quisiera saber como logra esto el sistema)

O debo escribir **una instrucción por cada equipo** que tenga este id_cliente registrado. Y si es así, como logro esto...

Gracias

Pdta: Solo necesito los datos de 4 columnas de la tabla equipos, por lo tanto no utilizo el asterisco * para seleccionar todo

Comment: Una sola instrucción para todos los equipos de un mismo cliente. Sería como : `select * from equipos where id_cliente = id`. La pregunta:  cómo logra eso el sistema? no me queda clara.

Comment: Según lo que yo comprendía de consultas, a la hora de ejecutar la instrucción el sistema verifica si alguna fila coincide con los datos proporcionados, en es caso sólo me devolvería un equipo. Pero yo necesito todos los equipos registrados con ese id_cliente. Eso es lo que no me queda claro, si solo busca una coincidencia o busca en todas las filas donde aparezca el id_cliente

Comment: Eso es correcto. La condición se ejecuta para todas las filas y selecciona las que cumplen los criterios.

Answer (score 0):

Hola debe hacer un inner join para consultar los equipos pertenecientes a un cliente

SELECT * FROM CLIENTES INNER JOIN EQUIPOS ON CLIENTES.IDCLIENTE=EQUIPOS.IDCLIENTE

En la tabla equipos tiene que estar un idcliente de un cliente para poder unirlos.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo para lograr eso debes hacer un  inner join con tus tablas clientes y equipos para relacionar los datos del equipo con los datos del cliente en una sola consulta, además debes usar un where para limitar los resultados  a un cliente en particular(en este ejemplo al cliente "Maria"). Aqui te dejo el ejemplo:

```
SELECT equipos.codigo, equipos.descripcion, equipos.precio from equipos JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = equipos.id_cliente WHERE clientes.nombre = 'Maria'
```

Espero haberte ayudado